# Qt сигналы и слоты в стороннем приложении

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю с библиотекой для игрового движка, появилась необходимость использовать функционал `QtNetwork` в этой библиотеке. Собственно подключил всё это дело через заголовочные файлы, библиотеки (Qt5Core и Qt5Network), а также добавил генерацию moc файлов для заголовочных файлов с макросом Q_OBJECT.

Создал простой класс с макросом `Q_OBJECT`

```
#ifndef _Network_H_
#define _Network_H_

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class CNetwork : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CNetwork(QObject *parent = 0);
public:
    void ConnectToServer();
public slots:
    void onConnectedToServer();
    void onReadyRead();
    void onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void onDisconnected();
private:
    bool connected;
    QTcpSocket* m_socket;
};

#endif
```

Реализация :

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Network.h"
#include "Global.h"


CNetwork::CNetwork(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}


void CNetwork::ConnectToServer()
{
    Log(TITLE "connecting...");

    int port = 3322;

    m_socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    m_socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", port);

    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::connected, this, &CNetwork::onConnectedToServer);
    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &CNetwork::onReadyRead);
    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::bytesWritten, this, &CNetwork::onBytesWritten);
    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &CNetwork::onDisconnected);

}

void CNetwork::onConnectedToServer()
{
    Log(TITLE "connected");
    connected = true;
}

void CNetwork::onReadyRead()
{
    Log(TITLE "readyRead");
}

void CNetwork::onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
{
    Log(TITLE "bytesWriten");
}

void CNetwork::onDisconnected()
{
    Log(TITLE "disconnected");
    connected = false;
}
```

Всё это дело прекрасно компилируется и даже подключается к серверу при вызове `ConnectToServer()`. Но сигналы и слоты отказываются работать. Я думаю, что дело в `event loop`, пробовал запускать всё это дело в отдельном потоке и создавал свой `event loop` :

```
QEventLoop* m_loop = new QEventLoop();
m_loop->exec();
```

Но это не помогло. В общем вопрос - как заставить работать сигналы и слоты в данном случае?

Comment: Вам нужно использовать экземпляр QApplication, который и запускает обработку событий.

Comment: Благодарю, это действительно помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение проблемы заключается в создании экземпляра `QCoreApplication` и запуска `event loop`'a.

Рабочий код выглядит следующим образом :

```
#ifndef _Network_H_
#define _Network_H_

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class CNetwork : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CNetwork(QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void onConnectedToServer();
    void onReadyRead();
    void onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void onDisconnected();
private:
    bool connected;
    QTcpSocket* m_socket;
public:
    void StartNetwork();
};

#endif
```

Реализация :

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Network.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>


CNetwork::CNetwork(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void CNetwork::StartNetwork()
{
    int argc = 0;
    char* argv[1] = {};
    QCoreApplication networker(argc, argv);

    Log(TITLE "Connecting to server...");

    int port = 3322;

    m_socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    m_socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", port);

    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::connected, this, &CNetwork::onConnectedToServer);
    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &CNetwork::onReadyRead);
    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::bytesWritten, this, &CNetwork::onBytesWritten);
    connect(m_socket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &CNetwork::onDisconnected);

    networker.exec();
}

void CNetwork::onConnectedToServer()
{
    Log(TITLE "connected");
    connected = true;
}

void CNetwork::onReadyRead()
{
    Log(TITLE "readyRead");
}

void CNetwork::onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
{
    Log(TITLE "bytesWriten");
}

void CNetwork::onDisconnected()
{
    Log(TITLE "disconnected");
    connected = false;
}
```

Использовать можно так - создать поток, в котором создать экземпляр нашего класса и запустить `StartNetwork()`. Пример :

```
#include "Network.h"
#include <thread>

void RunNetwork()
{
    CNetwork pNetwork;
    pNetwork.StartNetwork();

}

void CClass::ConnectToServer()
{
    std::thread nerworkThread(RunNetwork);
    nerworkThread.detach();
}
```

Спасибо за решение проблемы пользователю [Pavel Parshin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/196758/pavel-parshin)